# Multiple camera on single viewController with different overlays

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

How can i show `UIImagePickerController` "`Camera`" on two different `UIView` at the same time?

we all are aware about the opening imagePicker and even open that inside of some view with frame but my requirement is i have two `UIView` and inside of them i need to show camera both of that `UIView` has different overlays for camera i can show camera on one of them at a time but don't know how to open same camera output on both can anyone please help me!

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Use AVFoundation. You can't done it with UIImagePickerContoller

Comment: could you please give me some example of code for achieving that?

Answer (score 1):

You should try AVFoundation.

Apple has provided a best example for that..

You can download the example from [here...](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

This will help you....

Comment: Demo only shows 1 UIView with camera. I tried the same code to display 2nd UIView with camera but it did not work.

Comment: Could you explain in detail.